# Remove numbers from key of json in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, json

I find the following output in JSON as:

```
[{
    "ApplicationView": "",
    "Styling": "",
    "minwidth": "450px",
    "minheight": "350px",
    "kendoWindowWidth": "90%",
    "kendoWindowHeight": "90%",
    "iconSize": "20px",
    "viewerToolColor": "#8dcaf7",
    "DefaultView": "fit To Screen",
    "Email": "",
    "To": "ToPerson",
    "Subject": "This file is exported from actual program.",
    "From": "FromPerson",
    "Body": "This file is exported from actual program.",
    "Content": "",
    "zoomIn": "",
    "Icon16": "ZoomIn.png",
    "Label17": "Zoom In",
    "Visibility18": "true",
    "zoomOut": "",
    "Icon20": "ZoomOut.png",
    "Label21": "Zoom Out",
    "Visibility22": "true",
    "rotateLeft": null,
    "Icon24": "RotateLeft.png",
    "Label25": "Rotate Left",
    "Visibility26": "true",
    "rotateRight": "",
    "Icon28": "RotateRight.png",
    "Label29": "Rotate Right",
    "Visibility30": "true",
    "fitToScreen": "",
    "Icon32": "fittoscreen.png",
    "Label33": "Fit to Screen or Double Click on Image",
    "Visibility34": "true",
    "fullScreen": "",
    "Icon36": "fullscreen.png",
    "Label37": "Full Screen or 2 Times Double Click on Image",
    "Visibility38": "true",
    "saveAs": "",
    "Icon40": "download.png",
    "Label41": "Full Screen or 2 Times Double Click on Image",
    "Visibility42": "true",
    "print": "",
    "Icon44": "print.png",
    "Label45": "Print",
    "Visibility46": "true",
    "email": "Email",
    "Icon48": "email.png",
    "Label49": "Send Mail",
    "Visibility50": "true"
}]
```

I want to remove numbers from the keys of JSON

example: `icon48` would be `icon`.

Kindly guide me in doing this.

I was trying to access keys of `json` in `foreach` loop and using regular expression to remove numbers but did not succeed while doing it.

Help would be appreciated.

Comment: Firstly, do you have an actual JSON string, or do you have a javascript object? Secondly, what have you tried so far? (show us some code)

Comment: This or similar questions have to have been answered at least 100 times on SO. Please do a search.

Comment: I tried but none of it worked.I am working on it from past 5 hours.

Comment: so instead of "Icon16" you should have just "Icon"? And instead of "Icon20" you should have "Icon" as well? They cant have the same key?

Comment: No they cannot.When I was using then the keys got replaced.

Comment: I dont know why the people here keep on marking the question as repeated when they are not playing vital role as solution of my problem.I have searched and tried the solutions mentioned here.
Kindly,solve it then judge the question.

Answer (score 4):

Don't try to work directly on the JSON string : You *really* should parse it before changing it.

```
var arr1 = JSON.parse(yourJSON);
var arr2 = arr1.map(function(o1){
    var o2 = {};
    for (var key in o1) {
        o2[key.replace(/\d+/g,'')] = o1[key];
    }
    return o2;
});
var finalJSON = JSON.stringify(arr2);
```

Skip the first and last steps if you don't have, in fact, any JSON but just a plain JavaScript array.

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/4fHqL/1/)

Comment: Not working Sir.

myJsonString = JSON.stringify(yuiop);

yuiop is the name of the array where I have push all the values.

Comment: [It works in my tests](http://jsfiddle.net/4fHqL/). Can you check what you do differently ?

Comment: Dear Sir,Check your demonstration.After zoomout no icons,label and visiblity is displayed.